# I cannot ping freenode.net by any means from my desktop

Tags: networking

Strange! I can't get to freenode.net by any means from my desktop (using irc client, browser or weechat). But I can get to oftc.net and other irc networks from my desktop, and I can even get to freenode.net from my phone.

So my router is okay and I can ping the freenode IP 104.25.60.112 and  oftc.net but I can't ping freenode.net (special case) from my desktop. So for some reason my desktop cannot resolve the name freenode.net. My desktop setup was all good for freenode.net even yesterday (no modifications have been made).

How do I fix that?

FYI `# lsb_release -rd` returns

```
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
```

`ping` results:

```
$ ping 104.25.60.112
  PING 104.25.60.112 (104.25.60.112) 56(84) bytes of data.
  64 bytes from 104.25.60.112: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=59.9 ms
  64 bytes from 104.25.60.112: icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=61.1 ms
  64 bytes from 104.25.60.112: icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=60.0 ms
  64 bytes from 104.25.60.112: icmp_seq=4 ttl=57 time=59.9 ms
  64 bytes from 104.25.60.112: icmp_seq=5 ttl=57 time=59.8 ms
  64 bytes from 104.25.60.112: icmp_seq=6 ttl=57 time=60.1 ms
  64 bytes from 104.25.60.112: icmp_seq=7 ttl=57 time=60.6 ms
  64 bytes from 104.25.60.112: icmp_seq=8 ttl=57 time=62.4 ms

$ ping freenode.net
  ping: unknown host freenode.net

$ ping oftc.net
  PING oftc.net (206.12.19.247) 56(84) bytes of data.
  64 bytes from oftc.net (206.12.19.247): icmp_seq=1 ttl=50 time=228 ms
  64 bytes from oftc.net (206.12.19.247): icmp_seq=2 ttl=50 time=228 ms
  64 bytes from oftc.net (206.12.19.247): icmp_seq=3 ttl=50 time=228 ms
  64 bytes from oftc.net (206.12.19.247): icmp_seq=4 ttl=50 time=228 ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a restart the `/etc/resolv.conf` fix vanishes. So for a permanent solution I had to modify the `/etc/network/interfaces` and had to add a line `dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8` down to my LAN interface like this

```
auto enp4s0
iface enp4s0 inet dhcp
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

and then restarted the service by `systemctl restart networking.service` which fixed it permanently.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a problem with DNS.

Run this command to temporarily fix it if that is the case

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: Wow that worked and I dont know why my local gateway was working fine till yesterday as nameserver and now just not working only for freenode.net!

Comment: Im glad it worked

Comment: oops, that fix was temporary, for a permanent solution I had to modify the `/etc/network/interfaces` and had to add a line like this `dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8`